# Why I am having a syntax error while writing npm run dev

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, next.js, syntax-error

So i was working on an online chess project using next js. Everything was running smooth until this unknown error pops up

```
E:\Allprojects\NEXTAPPS\chess_online\node_modules\watchpack\lib\watchpack.js:1
$→��m��mo�L�D��;�%g�?w��ŷ↓�▬��ovH0��a�5��*�ؒ��l͛�S�iy☺�r�O7��
��%L]��%��∟�hk
 ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)      
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1178:20)   
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1220:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)    
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Allprojects\NEXTAPPS\chess_online\node_modules\next\dist\cli\next-dev.js:28:59)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)

Node.js v18.16.1
```

here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "chess_online",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "13.4.9",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.44.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.9"
  }
}
```

I have no idea what this error is about. I tried going back to my older git version but still it didnt
get the job done. I hope somebody have a solution for this.

Comment: What is it that you mean by "$→��m��mo�L�D��;�%g�?w��ŷ↓�▬��ovH0��a�5��*�ؒ��l͛�S�iy☺�r�O7��
��%L]��%��∟�hk"?

Comment: Take a look at that `watchpack.js` file and see how it looks.

Comment: "Everything was running smooth" until... what did you do? (a question we've all had to face at some point or other).

Comment: @Pointy This was the exact text written in the terminal 
 "$→��m��mo�L�D��;�%g�?w��ŷ↓�▬��ovH0��a�5��*�ؒ��l͛�S�iy☺�r�O7�� ��%L]��%��∟�hk"

Comment: I tried reseting back to my git version but nothing happened. @Andy

Comment: @Pointy I have no idea about the watchpack.js module. Should I reinstall that module or something?

Comment: The module is corrupted. Uninstall it and re-install it.

Comment: I mean seriously, you cannot possibly believe that that is what a JavaScript source code file is supposed to look like.